# Vuetify v-spacer has no effect

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In my modal **<v-dialog>**, I try stick one block to the bottom of the **<v-col>** block by using **<v-spacer>**, but it has no effect. What am I doing wrong?
**Example**:  https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-template-viov1?file=/src/App.vue
I also tried to solve this by adding **"d-flex flex-column"** to the parent's **col** class, but in that case size of each **row** is anomalous
https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-template-6wr6g

Thanks for any hints

Comment: so many v-col v-row s that is very hard to follow what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-template-yns2m?file=/src/App.vue

The problems are:

- Incorrect usage of v-container, v-row and v-col - causing the weird spacing issues.
- There should be a fixed height container for the v-spacer to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

not sure why you are using so many rows inside columns inside rows...
that's just the height of the row.

look at this example, I set a height and the spacer works:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-template-s3pe2?file=/src/App.vue